# SQL Query: find lots that belong to current auction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table auctions and a table lots:

```
mysql> select id, auction_name, auction_startdate, auction_planned_closedate from auctions;
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| id | auction_name | auction_startdate   | auction_planned_closedate |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|  1 | Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |
|  2 | Auction 2    | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       |
|  3 | Auction 3    | 2016-07-01 00:00:00 | 2016-08-30 00:00:00       |
|  4 | Auction 4    | 2016-09-01 00:00:00 | 2016-10-30 00:00:00       |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+

mysql> select id, auction_id, lot_name from lots;
+----+------------+----------+
| id | auction_id | lot_name |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 | Lot 1    |
|  2 |          1 | Lot 2    |
|  3 |          1 | Lot 3    |
|  4 |          1 | Lot 4    |
|  5 |          1 | Lot 5    |
|  6 |          1 | Lot 6    |
|  7 |          1 | Lot 7    |
|  8 |          2 | Lot 8    |
|  9 |          2 | Lot 9    |
| 10 |          2 | Lot 10   |
| 11 |          3 | Lot 11   |
| 12 |          3 | Lot 12   |
| 13 |          3 | Lot 13   |
| 14 |          3 | Lot 14   |
| 15 |          4 | Lot 15   |
| 16 |          4 | Lot 16   |
+----+------------+----------+
```

I want to display only the lots for current auctions (which are auctions 1 and 2 in the example), in other words for which the current time is between the 'auction_startdate' and 'auction_planned_closedate'.

So here is what I want to achieve:

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------+
| auction_name | auction_startdate   | auction_planned_closedate | lots_id |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------+
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  1      |
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  2      |
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  3      |
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  4      |
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  5      |
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  6      |
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |  7      |
| Auction 2    | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       |  8      |
| Auction 2    | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       |  9      |
| Auction 2    | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       | 10      |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------+
```

The following query gets me the current auctions:

```
mysql> select auction_name, auction_startdate, auction_planned_closedate from auctions where now() >= auction_startdate and now() <= auction_planned_closedate; 
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| auction_name | auction_startdate   | auction_planned_closedate |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| Auction 1    | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       |
| Auction 2    | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

and then I do an inner join with the 'lots' table:

```
select auction_name, auction_startdate, auction_planned_closedate, lots.id
from auctions
where now() >= auction_startdate
  and now() <= auction_planned_closedate
inner join lots on auctions.id = lots.auction_id;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'inner join lots on auctions.id=lots.auction_id' at
>   line 1

I'm getting a syntax error which I'm staring blind at for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong order, put the `WHERE` clause after the `JOIN`:

```
select auction_name, auction_startdate, auction_planned_closedate, lots.id
from auctions
inner join lots on auctions.id = lots.auction_id
where now() >= auction_startdate
  and now() <= auction_planned_closedate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `join` is in the wrong order:

```
select a.auction_name, a.auction_startdate, a.auction_planned_closedate, l.id
from auctions a inner join
      lots l
      on a.id = l.auction_id
where now() >= a.auction_startdate and now() <= a.auction_planned_closedate ;
```

Notes:

- `where` goes after the `from` clause.  `join` is *not* a separate clause; it is an operator in the `from` clause.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all the column names.  This makes it clear where the columns are coming from.

Comment: For once I typed faster!

Comment: And both are correct :-) Quick additional question: in Gordon's answer he uses inner join lots l. Why the additional 'l'?

Comment: @wiwa1978, that's a table alias. Very convenient way to spare some typing, in the query just use the table alias instead of the table name.